# php variables: how to echo working anchor-link without / before #

Tags: php, variables, echo, anchor

Dear PHP professionals

I am trying to generate an anchor-link out of some php-variables.

```
<?php if (get_field('textfeld-01')) : ?>
        <?php
            $anchor = "#"; 
            $field_name = "textfeld-01";
            $field = get_field_object($field_name);
            echo '<a href=" ' . $anchor . $field['label'] .' ">' .  $field['label'] . '</a>';
            ; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

This is my output:

```
http://live.bernhard-schrammek.de/taetigkeiten/#Texte
```

I have to eliminate the last slash, as you all know, to generate the working anchor-link:

```
http://live.bernhard-schrammek.de/taetigkeiten#Texte
```

Is anybody able to show me a solution for that? My PHP level is still "try and error" :-(

Thank you and best regards from Berlin

Tibor

Comment: Use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) before concatenating the `#` part.

Comment: I just don't see how you concatenate `$anchor` (which is `#`) first and it ends up in the end...

Answer (score 0):

Try a basic string replace?

```
$url = str_replace('/#', '#', $url);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php

$url = 'http://live.bernhard-schrammek.de/taetigkeiten/#Texte';

echo str_replace('/#', '#', $url);
```

Live example here https://3v4l.org/UW490

Comment: Hi delboy1978uk Thank you for your fast support! May I ask you one more question? The Parts after the Page URL "#" and "Texte" are variables and come from `$anchor = "#";` and `$field = get_field_object($field_name)`. You know that, of course. Your solution works well as you proofed and I guess I did a mistake while trying to implement it. Could you be so kind to show an example where to set these both variables? Sorry to ask again. Best regards!

Comment: Sorry what I wrote abouve is nonsens :-) The question is how to set variables to generate the URL out the page-URL and the variable `$field = get_field_object($field_name)`. How to implement and to delete the `#` you explained and solved. Sorry.

Comment: If you have an array, you can pass it into `http_build_query()`, which will build your query string. Check here for an example: https://3v4l.org/h1BK1 . So you can just add a `?` to the end followed by the query string.